# re.sub replacing too much text

Tags: python, regex

I have a set of links like:

```
['http://www.nytimes.com/2016/12/31/us/politics/house-republicans-health-care-suit.html?partner=rss&amp;emc=rss" rel="standout"></atom:link>',
 'http://www.nytimes.com/2016/12/31/nyregion/bronx-murder-40th-precinct-police-residents.html</guid>',
 'http://www.nytimes.com/2016/12/30/movies/tyrus-wong-dies-bambi-disney.html?partner=rss&amp;emc=rss',
 'http://www.nytimes.com/2016/12/30/obituaries/among-deaths-in-2016-a-heavy-toll-in-pop-music.html</guid>',
 'http://www.nytimes.com/video/world/100000004830728/daybreak-around-the-world.html?partner=rss&amp;emc=rss']
```

I'm trying to iterate over them to remove everything that comes after `html`. So I have:

```
cleanitems = []

for item in links:  
    cleanitems.append(re.sub(r'html(.*)', '', item))
```

Which returns:

```
['http://www.nytimes.com/2016/12/31/us/politics/house-republicans-health-care-suit.',
 'http://www.nytimes.com/2016/12/31/nyregion/bronx-murder-40th-precinct-police-residents.',
 'http://www.nytimes.com/2016/12/30/movies/tyrus-wong-dies-bambi-disney.',
 'http://www.nytimes.com/2016/12/30/obituaries/among-deaths-in-2016-a-heavy-toll-in-pop-music.',
 'http://www.nytimes.com/video/world/100000004830728/daybreak-around-the-world.]
```

Confused as to why it's including `html` in the capture group. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You also remove `html`. Put `html` into the replacement string to keep it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`html` is part of the matched text *too*, not just the `(...)` group. `re.sub()` replaces all of the whole matched text.

Include the literal `html` text in the replacement:

```
cleanitems.append(re.sub(r'html(.*)', 'html', item))
```

or, alternatively, capture that part in a group instead:

```
cleanitems.append(re.sub(r'(html).*', r'\1', item))
```

You may want to consider using a non-greedy match, and a `$` end-of-string anchor to prevent cutting off a URL that contains `html` in the path more than once, and including the `.` dot to make sure you are really only matching the `.html` extension:

```
cleanitems.append(re.sub(r'\.html.*?$', r'.html', item))
```

However, if your goal is to remove the *query string* from a URL, consider parsing the URL using [`urllib.parse.urlparse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse), and re-building it without the query string or fragment identifiers:

```
from urlib.parse import urlparse

cleanitems.append(urlparse(item)._replace(query='', fragment='').geturl())
```

This won't remove the eroneous HTML chunks however; if you are parsing these URLs from a HTML document, consider using a [real HTML parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) rather than regex.

Comment: Interesting, I figured it only captured the parenthese'd group. Also I guess I included `''` out of habit of getting rid of bad characters. Will accept answer in 9 minutes when SO lets me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just a complement to Martijn's answer.

You could also use a lookbehind assertion to only match the text following `html`:

```
cleanitems.append(re.sub(r'(?<=html).*', '', item))
```

or use a replacement string to keep the initial part:

```
cleanitems.append(re.sub(r'(html).*', r'\1', item))
```

But as already said by Martin, you'd better use the urllib module to correctly parse URLs